# Ruta: How can I read a text file, line by line, considering each line as one string

Tags: java, uima, ruta

Using a Ruta script I tried to read a text file that has multiple lines and each one of them multiple words.

I used WORDLIST and STRINGLIST,

WORDLIST personNameList = 'PersonName.txt';

STRINGLIST pList = { "John", "Paul Newton" };

but both, although work well when a line contains just one word, don't seem to work when a line contains multiple words.

Comment: Whats wrong with FileReader + BufferedReader / Scanner ?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you want to accomplish? I assume that you want to apply the txt file as a dictionary, right? If that's so, have you considered the whitespaces in the dictionary. Try to remove them all, if you have default filtering setting in your script file.

Comment: Hi Peter, what I want is to iterate through the items of the STRINGLIST -the lines read from the text file- 
and for each one of them, check if it exists in a given text and annotate it.

Comment: The WORLDLIST should just work fine. The STRINGLIST can be more tricky because that results in windowing over candidates what should be avoided. Can you please add your complete example, e.g., how you try to annotate the text? WORDLISTS are normally applied with MARKFAST.